# Problema con System.Windows.Forms en una aplicación de consola

Tags: c#, consola

Uso VS 2017 y win 10, estoy haciendo una aplicación de consola sencilla, quiero usar el **portapapeles**, para ello incluyo
`using System.Windows.Forms`;

Pero me sale el error:

> El tipo o nombre del espacio de nombres Forms no existe en el espacio
>   System.Windows ¿falta alguna referencia de ensamblado?

Si pongo punto y espero el intellisense luego de Windows no me sale como opción Forms.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[STAThreadAttribute]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String comando = "Inicio";
            String respuesta = "";
            //int[] vector;

            Console.WriteLine("CLI asp.net mvc");
            Console.WriteLine("Introduzca su opción");

            do
            {
                comando = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (comando)
                {
                    case "hp":
                        respuesta = "[HttpPost]";
                        break;
                    case "hv":
                        respuesta = "[HttpPost]" + Environment.NewLine + "[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]";
                        break;
                    case "vaft":
                        respuesta = "[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]";
                        break;

                }
                Clipboard.SetText(respuesta);
                //Clippy.PushStringToClipboard(respuesta);
                Clippy.PushUnicodeStringToClipboard(respuesta);

                Console.WriteLine(respuesta);
            } while (comando != "salir");

            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
```

En clipboard me sale:

> Clipboard no existe en el contexto actual

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para utilizar el ensamblado **`System.Windows.Forms`** en una aplicación de Consola, debes añadirlo tu mismo "a mano" en el proyecto.

En tu proyecto, haz click derecho en **Referencias > Añadir referencia** y en **Ensamblados** busca **`System.Windows.Forms`** y añadelo al proyecto.

Comment: Es cierto, muchas gracias Rafael Acosta... había intentado con administrar paquetes nuget y no había podido.

Comment: @Hernandez400 si esta respuesta te ha ayudado, considera marcarla como aceptada, indicando a futuros usuarios que esta respuesta es la correcta. Un saludo y bienvenido a [es.so]